# Проблема с физикой в Арканоиде

Tags: c++, visual-c++, разработка-игр

Недавно занялся по гайдам делать арканоид. Возникла проблема с физикой шарика. Функция automoveBall() должна определять местоположение шарика в пространстве и заставлять его отталкиваться от стен, но что то пошло не так и шарик просто скользит по стенке до угла и остается там.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


const double M_PI = 3.14;

#define shirina 65
#define visota 25
typedef struct
{
    int x, y;
    int w;

}TRacket;

typedef struct
{
    float x, y;
    int ix, iy;
    float alfa;
    float speed;
}TBall;

char mass[visota][shirina + 1];
TRacket racket;
TBall ball;

void moveBall(int x, int y)
{
    ball.x = x;
    ball.y = y;
    ball.ix = (int)round(ball.x);
    ball.iy = (int)round(ball.y);
}

void initBall()
{
    moveBall(2, 2);
    ball.alfa = -2;
    ball.speed = 1;
}

void putBall()
{
    mass[ball.iy][ball.ix] = '*';
}

void automoveBall()
{
    TBall bl = ball;
    if (ball.alfa < 0) ball.alfa += (M_PI * 2);
    if (ball.alfa > (M_PI * 2))ball.alfa -= (M_PI * 2);

    
    moveBall(ball.x + cos(ball.alfa) * ball.speed, ball.y + sin(ball.alfa) * ball.speed);

    if ((mass[ball.iy][ball.ix] == '#') || (mass[ball.iy][ball.ix] == '@'))
    {
        if ((ball.ix != bl.ix) && (ball.iy != bl.iy))
        {
            if (mass[bl.iy][ball.ix] == mass[ball.iy][bl.ix])
                bl.alfa = (bl.alfa + M_PI);
            else
            {
                if (mass[bl.iy][ball.ix] == '#')
                    bl.alfa = (2 * M_PI - bl.alfa) + M_PI;
                else
                    bl.alfa = (2 * M_PI - bl.alfa);
            }
        }
        else if (ball.iy == bl.iy)
            bl.alfa = (2 * M_PI - bl.alfa) + M_PI;
        else
            bl.alfa = (2 * M_PI - bl.alfa);


        ball = bl;
        automoveBall();

   }



}
void initRacket()//Данные ракетки
{
    racket.w = 12;
    racket.x = (shirina - racket.w) / 2;
    racket.y = visota - 1;
}

void PutRacket()//Появление ракетки
{
    for (int i = racket.x; i < racket.x + racket.w; i++)
        mass[racket.y][i] = '@';
}
void init()//Карта
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shirina; i++)
        mass[0][i] = '#';
    mass[0][shirina] = '\0';

  
    strncpy_s(mass[1], mass[0], shirina + 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < shirina-1; i++)
        mass[1][i] = ' ';
    

    for (int i = 2; i < visota; i++)
        strncpy_s(mass[i], mass[1], shirina+1);
}



void show() //Отображение карты
{
    for (int i = 0; i < visota; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", mass[i]);
        if (i < visota - 1)printf("\n");
    }
}

void moveRacket(int x)
{
    racket.x = x;
    if (racket.x < 1)
        racket.x = 1;
    if (racket.x + racket.w >= shirina)
        racket.x = shirina - 1 - racket.w;
}

void setcur(int x, int y)

{
    HANDLE  handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO structCursorInfo;
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(handle, &structCursorInfo);
    structCursorInfo.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(handle, &structCursorInfo);
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

int main()//Игра
{
    char put;
    BOOL run = FALSE;
   //pres();
  // pres1();
   initRacket();
   initBall();
   do
   {
       setcur(0, 0);

       if (run)
           automoveBall();

       init();
       PutRacket();
       putBall();
       show();
     
       if (GetKeyState('A')<0)moveRacket(racket.x - 1);
       if (GetKeyState('D')<0)moveRacket(racket.x + 1);
       if (GetKeyState('W') < 0)run=TRUE;
       if(!run)
            moveBall(racket.x + racket.w / 2, racket.y-1 );
       Sleep(10);

   }
   while (GetKeyState (VK_ESCAPE)>=0);
    
   return(0);

}
```

Comment: Не нужны вам углы. Вместо этого используйте два компонента скорости vx и vy.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало.